# Minecraft just started crashing

Tags: java, minecraft

Minecraft just started to crash after some time of Ubuntu not being used. This is the error information the Launcher gives me.

```
-- System Details --
    Details:
        Minecraft Version: 1.8.7
        Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.16.0-43-generic
        CPU: 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T7700 @ 2.40GHz
        Java Version: 1.8.0_45, Oracle Corporation
        Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
        Memory: 28908808 bytes (27 MB) / 154734592 bytes (147 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
        JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
        IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
        Launched Version: 1.8.7
        LWJGL: 2.9.4
        OpenGL: Gallium 0.4 on NV84 GL version 1.4 (3.0 Mesa 10.3.2), nouveau
        GL Caps: 
        Using VBOs: No
        Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
        Type: Client (map_client.txt)
        Resource Packs: []
        Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
        Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

Comment: You need more details. Just telling us you use minecraft 1.8.7 in Linux on java 8 doesn't help anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. Look through [this Minecraft Forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/1857101-help-cant-start-minecraft-no-matter-what).
2. Upgrade your graphics card
3. Upgrade LWJGL
4. Get a new graphics card

Hopefully one of those works or the crash changes.